# Google Ads API test customer account Cannot Create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-ads-api

I created a test manager account and tried to get metrics for this account.
But I getting an error as :

> The developer token is not approved. Non-approved developer tokens can only be used with test accounts.

So I tried to create a customer account on Web GUI but in this time a getting an error like that:

> Billing setups can not be used based on current status of the customer.

So I checked my accounts and the GUI like that:

So, How can I create a customer account from this test manager account?

[image]

Comment: Could you solve this? I step into the same problem, and my test account has the red label for tests accounts

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's a test account? It doesn't look like one as it doesn't have the huge red ribbon saying that it's a test account that's present in all test accounts.

It looks like you just created a regular account with a test email address.

You should create a test account here: https://adwords.google.com/um/Welcome/Home?a=1&sf=mt&authuser=0#ta